# How do I replace GRUB with the Windows 8 bootloader without losing access to Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-8, grub, multi-boot, grub2

I dual-boot Windows 8 and Crunchbang Linux. I installed Windows first, then Linux. GRUB was installed directly in the MBR.

However, now I suspect that GRUB is the reason why I can't use `bcdedit` on Windows, so I'd like to restore the default Windows bootloader. How can I do it without breaking Linux?

Comment: You would have to restore the Windows bootloader, typically from the Windows installation media, and then add a boot option that chainloads GRUB - I believe EasyBCD can do that.

Comment: Turns out the reason why I couldn't use `bcdedit` was that my Linux `/boot` partition was located at the start of the hard drive. Apparently Windows doesn't like that. All I had to do was delete it, move my Windows partition to the start, then run `bootrec /fixboot` and `bootrec /fixmbr` to inform Windows of the change. Now Windows lets me use `bcdedit`.

My Linux installation is still inaccesible (and without a `/boot` directory to boot - no pun intended) but I'll try reinstalling GRUB to the Linux partition and running EasyBCD on Windows to make it accessible from the outside.